# Azure B2C Custom Policy , Add Custom User Attribute in Output Claims

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created custom policy for Interactive login in Azure AAD B2C
The Sign In / Sign Up works fine
However now I added Custom User Attribute in my B2C thru Portal, and updated so my custom policy also for "extension_UserRole" custom policy
However it is not showing in sign in as well as JWT , Below is my custom policy

https://github.com/menikhilmittal/policyb2c

Please suggest changes

Comment: I am not aware how to debug custom policy, please suggest or changes if any

Answer (score 1):

Input claims are used to pre-populate fields.

You need to give the extension attribute a value (CopyClaim? from another attribute) and have it as an output in both read and write.

If an output in sign up e.g. it will create a text box that you can populate.

You have also used both email and login hint to populate it?

Comment: Hello Sir
Please elaborate what changes i need to do , i m a bit newbie in b2c custom policy